# C - Read hex number and check if less then zero scanf()

Tags: c, hex, scanf

I'm writing a program in C which reads a hexadecimal number with `scanf()` and I want to check if the value is valid. But if I write -5 it shows that the input is valid. Is there some easy way to check if the input is less then zero or do I have to read it as signed and then change it?

```
unsigned int number;
scanf("%x",&number);
if (....) {
    printf("Invalid input!\n");
}
```

Comment: Because `%x` reads in an unsigned integer and unsigned integers are by *definition always non-negative*.

Comment: So what is it that you expect?

Comment: If the user writes -5 I would like it to print Invalid input.

Comment: but the result is a valid positive value `UINT_MAX + 1 - 5 `

Comment: or do you mean that the number mustn't have a sign at all?

Comment: It's a good point: I would expect the input to be terminated at the `-` just as it would be terminated at `z` if `"z5"` is input. MSVC accepts `"-5"` and `scanf` returns a value of `1`.

Comment: You should test the return value from `scanf()` to see whether it was successful.  Nevertheless, negative values can be read.  POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) says: _`x` Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of `strtoul()` with the value 16 for the base argument. In the absence of a size modifier, the application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to `unsigned`._

Comment: Aside: the result is at the mercy of an uninitialised variable, and an unchecked `scanf` function return value.

Comment: So `-5` is a proper encoding (writing) of a hexadecimal number: the hexadecimal representation of `-5`.

Comment: Two things: Always check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Secondly, if `scanf` fails to parse the input according to the format, it will leave the input in the buffer.

Comment: Rhea , What should input `"-0"` return? `"Invalid input!"` or `0`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some easy way to check if the input is less then zero

`"%x"` accepts input like `"-123"` and forms an `unsigned` positive value of `UINT_MAX + 1 - 123`.  So that alone is not enough.

Alternatively, look for the `'-'` yourself.

Below uses `"%n"` to detect if scanning succeeded past the 1 or more `'-'` (scanned with `"%*[-]"`).  If no leading `'-'`, nothing but leading spaces consumed and `n` remains 0.

```
  int n = 0;
  scanf(" %*[-]%n", &n);
  if (n) {
    printf("Invalid negative input!\n");
  } else if (scanf("%x",&number) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid non-hex input!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Success %x\n", number);
  }
```

---

Unclear what OP wants to do should invalid input occur.

---

A better approach would use `fgets()` to read a line of user input and then parse that.

```
 char buf[80];
 if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) {
   unsigned int number;
   if (strchr(buf, '-') == NULL && sscanf(buf, "%x", &number) == 1) {
     printf("Success %x\n", number);
   } else {
     printf("Fail\n");
   }
}
```

Even better code would use `strtoul()` and not `sscanf()`.